# HttpClient.execute always gives Exception

Tags: java, android, httpclient

I tried to bring HTML of a web and i use this code for doing this :

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com");
    HttpResponse response;
    try {
        response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and always in the `response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);` it give me exception, also in other codes that i tried

Comment: which exception and what is the output (stacktrace, error message)?

Comment: Could you post the error message you see in LogCat please?

Comment: java.net.UnknownHostException: www.google.com

Comment: seems like network setting on your machine is not right. Are you using proxy?

Comment: "java.net.UnknownHostException" - It can't resolve the host which basically means it can't get access to a DNS server to lookup the address. As Mi Mee said, your network isn't configured correctly. Make sure there aren't any firewall issues and that you've configured things to use any proxy server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried setting the [`INTERNET`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) permission in the manifest file?

Sample code:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="sample.hello"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">

<!--- Here is where you put your permissions. --->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".HelloWorld"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: i new in this android stuff, so where i can add it?

Comment: Can you post the error log, which you can find using DDMS? Also, where in the manifest file did you add the permission tag? I have added another edit.